# How would I create the missing row values in pyhton for two inbetween dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

The idea is that I have a Data Frame that looks something like this:

```
In [1]: pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2020', '0:00', 807, 1600], ['3/1/2020', '1:00', 4000, 8000],], columns=['Date', 'Hour', 'X', 'Y'])
```

I have simplified the code becuase I am only interested in the things that are inbetween.

[image]

Date is in (dd/mm/yyyy) format.
Is there some simple way to create the values that are missing that is 2/1/2020 and in X and Y add Nan so it would end up looking like this:

[image]

I have to do this with a much bigger that data frame but for simple use I used a small portion of the Data frame. The only method I have thought of is creating the rows and adding nan to the rows, but I want to believe there is a much easier way. This is the Link to the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NrDBkqfMO2rA631aA4FSmM2vJYDZCFbF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's a lot of work to answer with your data as pictures, but if you work with the `datetime64[ns]` dtype and create a `DatetimeIndex` then it's as simple as [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html)

Comment: I will update and add a link to the data

Comment: Okay Np I will update the comment with a working dataframe

Comment: So now I have edited the question it has pictures to exemplify and code for the database and also the data in a link I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update using @ALollz suggestion:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2020', '0:00', 807, 1600], ['3/1/2020', '1:00', 4000, 8000],['3/1/2020', '2:00', 5000, 9000], ['3/1/2020', '5:00', 5000, 9000]], columns=['Date', 'Hour', 'X', 'Y'])
# add column with datetime from Date and Hour
df['dateHour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Hour'])
df = df.set_index('dateHour').asfreq('H')
# split date from time and convert back to string
df['Date'] = ([d.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for d in df3['dateHour']])
df['Hour'] = [d.time().strftime("%H:%M") for d in df3['dateHour']]
```

Don't know if there is a more elegant way, but you can do it like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/2020', '0:00', 807, 1600], ['3/1/2020', '1:00', 4000, 8000],['3/1/2020', '2:00', 5000, 9000], ['3/1/2020', '5:00', 5000, 9000]], columns=['Date', 'Hour', 'X', 'Y'])
# add datetime column
df['dateHour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Hour'])
# create new dataframe with all the possible rows
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dateHour':pd.date_range(df.dateHour.min(), df.dateHour.max(), freq='H')})
# combine the dataframes
df3 = df2.merge(df[['dateHour', 'X', 'Y']], how='left', on='dateHour')
# split date from time and convert back to string
df3['Date'] = ([d.date().strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for d in df3['dateHour']])
df3['Hour'] = [d.time().strftime("%H:%M") for d in df3['dateHour']]
# select and sort columns
df4=df3[['Date', 'Hour', 'X', 'Y']]
df4
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly preprocess your excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('Trial.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
df=df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],yearfirst=True,format='%y-%d-%m').dt.strftime('%y-%d-%m')
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%y-%m-%d')
```

Now create a date range by using `date_range()` method:

```
data=pd.date_range('2020-01-02','2020-01-03',freq='H').astype(str)
```

Then create a new dataframe using that date range:

```
datadf=data.str.split(' ',expand=True).to_frame().set_index([0,1]).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Date',1:'Hour'})
```

Now make use of `concat()` method and concat both dataframes:

```
result=pd.concat((df,datadf),ignore_index=True)
```

Now Convert your 'Date' column in datetime by using `to_datetime()` method:

```
result['Date']=pd.to_datetime(result['Date'])
```

Finally sort your 'Date' column by using `sort_values()` method:

```
result=result.sort_values('Date',ignore_index=True)
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output